# Dropwizard: Is a .yml config mandatory?

Tags: java, configuration, dropwizard

I've got a basic `Dropwizard v1.2.0` application. I can execute it from my command line by running:

```
java -jar application.jar server config.yml
```

Is it possible for Dropwizard to work without passing it a `config.yml` file?

I'm asking because, right now, my `config.yml` looks like this:

```
mySetting: ${DW_MY_SETTING}
defaultSetting: ${DW_DEFAULT_SETTING:-default value}
```

I'm using the `'DW_MY_SETTING'` and `'DW_DEFAULT_SETTING'` environment variables to populate `config.yml`, and then the values in config.yml are being used to set `MyConfiguration.java` (that's the name of my class that extends io.dropwizard.Configuration).

Can I just set `MyConfiguration.java` directly from the environment variables and not bother going through a `config.yml` file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to utilize `io.dropwizard.Configuration` without specifying a YAML file then you need to advise it to ignore JSON properties like this:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class EnvironmentOnlyConfig extends Configuration {
    public static String getDwMySetting() {
        return System.getenv("DW_MY_SETTING");
    }
}
```